# Create a username attribute from the first 4 letters of first and last name, Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, substr

I have a Customer table in Oracle, which contains the first and last name of a customer.

I want to create a new attribute (column) called 'username' which consists of the first 4 letters of first name and the four first letters of last name.

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(USERNAME)
SELECT SUBSTR(CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME,0,4)||SUBSTR(CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME,0,4)
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

But unfortunately I get this error: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400:
Any ideas on how it should be done?

Comment: Please see minimal complete example on how to phrase your question. It lacks any schemas and we can't really help without something concrete. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "Doesn't work" is the least helpful phrase anyone includes in their questions.  Include *exact* and *reproducible* information.  Do you get error messages?  If so, include them!  Does it run, but give unexpected results?  If so, show your test cases, the results you expect, and the results you got.  It's not rocket science; we're not telepaths!

Comment: Aren't usernames normally unique? How many `JohnSmit`s is it OK to have? http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve

Comment: Please post a description of  CUSTOMER table, showing which columns are mandatory (not null).

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` adds rows, not columns. So your insert statement tries to generate a new set of rows from the existing rows in the table. It fails because these new rows only populate the `username` column but clearly at least one of the other table columns is null; because you're not populating any mandatory column the insert fails with `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ...`

First, you need to create the *(empty)* column...

```
ALTER TABLE customer
  ADD username VARCHAR2(8);  -- make sure YOU chose the correct data type for your needs.
```

Then you need to populate that column with the values you want...

```
UPDATE customer
  SET username = SUBSTR(CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME,0,4)||SUBSTR(CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME,0,4)
```

This, however, may not give unique results *(you don't say if that's required)*.

Answer (score 0):

> *Reasons to get* **ORA-01400**
>
> It seems you are trying to `INSERT` null values for non-listed
>   columns of your `INSERT` statement (the columns other than `USERNAME` column of `CUSTOMER` table),
>   at least one of them is defined with `not null` constraint.
>
> **OR**
>
> You have an `INSERT` trigger under `CUSTOMER` table, which tries to insert `null` value for a `not null` defined column of any
>   table.

I recommend you create a `VIEW` to hold your `CUSTOMERS_NICK_NAME`, instead of multiplexing your data by creating a table, and query this view whenever you need customers' informations :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_CUSTOMER AS 
SELECT CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME,
       SUBSTR(CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME,0,4)||SUBSTR(CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME,0,4) CUSTOMER_NICK_NAME
  FROM CUSTOMER;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting ORA-01400 because you are trying to insert null values into not null column. Following statement makes the customer.username column nullable:

```
alter table
   customer
modify
   (username NULL);
```

Comment: It seems the OP is adding a new column to an existing populated table. Consequently the `username` must already be nullable: Oracle won't allow us to add a NOT NULL to a populated table.

Comment: Actually, there is a workaround to do that. First add a new column (which isn't constrained), and then ALTER TABLE and modify the USERNAME column to be NOT NULL **NOVALIDATE**. Existing records will remain with an empty USERNAME, while newly added ones have to have some value.